# Rename record attribute after setting with scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a new scaffold (I assume that's how that process is described) as such:

```
rails g scaffold status name:string context:text
```

However I intended to type "content" instead of "context". I've executed the migration but now have no idea how to make the change across the app.

I am extremely new to Ruby, so I am sure the answer is trivial, I just have had a hard time searching when I hardly know the verbiage within the framework to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
bundle exec rake db:rollback
```

edit your migration and run

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

next, edit your newly generated `_form.html.erb`, `show.html.erb` and `index.html.erb` views and your `status_params` method in controller and it should be enough.

Comment: This worked. To expound on it slightly:

Executed the rollback. Then went into the original migration, status model, views, and controller files to locate any "context" that needed to be replaced with "content". Did that, then executed the migration. 

Restarted rails server and, after a few frustrating minutes, realized I should probably clear my browser cache. Worked like a charm.

I would've thought there was a more intuitive way than digging through all the files and manually editing before remigrating though. Hmmmm....